# UITextfield mimic Dropdown (UITableView?)

Tags: uitableview, ios4, xcode4, uitextfield

I want to add the feature that when i tap on a specific textfield, then there is a Dropdown / TableView in front of the gui and i can select a value and then the selected value is then inserted into the textfield?

How to achieve this in the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if this is on the iPad, you can use UIPopoverController and present a UITableViewController inside it.

If not, you can present a UIActionSheet and add UIPickerView or a UITableView inside it...in this example, I am creating a UIActionSheet and placing a UIPickerView inside it:

```
    NSString *title = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" : @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" ;
            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                          initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", title, [entry objectForKey:@"Name"]]
                                          delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[actionSheet setDelegate:self];
[actionSheet setTag:row];

pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[pv setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[pv setDelegate:self];
[pv setTag:28];
[actionSheet addSubview:pv];
[actionSheet showInView:[[[self navigationController] tabBarController] view]];
[pv release];
```

Notice the "\n"s, you need those to make room for the Picker view. Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: i get many errors and wanrings (undeclared identifier 'self'?)

Comment: use of undeclared identifier 'entry', [actionSheet setDelegate:self]; => expected identifier or '(', use of undeclared identifier 'row', [pv setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES]; => expected identifier or '('

Comment: Ok these are simple fixes, please read some books/guides on programming and start from the basics.

Comment: well i need an example that works and also a a small tutorial how i can implement this  if you develope an app in 1 week (just the part missing with pickerview) and are short before release do you then start reading the huge documentation (and also bad documented) of apple or a whole 500 pages book?

Comment: also i wanted a solution without actionsheet and with tableview like written in the question!